# Finding the limit of a lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I've made an attempt at the following question but am not sure if I'm heading in the right direction:

"Evaluate the limit of the following integral

$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{[0,1]} (\frac{1 - sin^2 (x)}{n})^6 dm(x)$"

My attempt is as follows:

Let $f(x) = (\frac{1 - sin^2(x)}{n})^6$

Then $\frac{sin^2(x)}{n} \leq \frac{sin^2(x)}{n + 1}$ $\leftrightarrow$ $\frac{1 - sin^2(x)}{n} \geq \frac{1 - sin^2(x)}{n+1}$ $\leftrightarrow$ $(\frac{1 - sin^2(x)}{n})^6 \geq (\frac{1 - sin^2(x)}{n+1})^6$

I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct and any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The $\sin^2(x)^6$ is confusing - is the entire fraction supposed to be raised to the $6^{\mathrm{th}}$ power, as your work suggests?

Comment: Sorry, yes it is. Edited to reflect this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well $1-\sin(x)^2 = \cos(x)^2$ so we have that $| (\frac{1-\sin^2(x)}{n})^6| \leq \frac{1}{n^6}$. So by lebesgues dominated convergence we may pass the limit inside the integral, and we get:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{[0,1]} (\frac{1-\sin^2(x)}{n})^6 dm(x) = \int_{[0,1]}0dm(x) = 0.
$$

Comment: Fantastic, thanks very much. So would what I have done be useless / wrong?

Comment: Yeah - your first inequality is wrong, as dividing with a larger number decreases the value (since $\sin$ is positive in your interval).

Comment: Why use the DCT? The integral equals $(1/n^6)\int_0^1(1-\sin^2 x)^6< 1/n^6\to 0$

Comment: Right - thought of that after posting. Well I guess one sometimes hit the problem with a hammer somewhat larger than the problem require.